# jQuery animation doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I made a simple animation in jquery, but it not always working. In particular:

```
$(".small-header").animate({top: "0"}, 500);
```

transitions faster than it should. It looks like animation works only on first time. I don't know why.

```js
$(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var top = $(document).scrollTop();
        console.log(top);
        if (top > 160) 
        {
            $(".small-header").css("display", "block");
            $(".small-header").animate({top: "0"}, 500);
            $(".big-header").css("display", "none");
        }
        if (top < 160)
        {
            $(".small-header").css("top", "-5em");
            $(".small-header").css("display", "none");
            $(".big-header").css("display", "block");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body
{
  height: 1000px;
}
.big-header
{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 10em;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: solid #aaaaaa 1px;
}
.small-header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 4em;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: solid #aaaaaa 1px;
    position: fixed;
    top: -5em;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="big-header">
</div>
<div class="small-header">
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bejkrools/yeddoddf/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('el').animate({left: "+=100px"}, 500);
alert('Debug!');
```

You will see that the alert appears before the animation ends, because animations are executed *asynchronously*.
This means that the element is first moved 1px (for ex.), then animation stops. The rest of the code executes, and a few milliseconds later the object is moved one more pixels to the right. And a few milliseconds later again.
So actually animations continue after the rest of the code executes.

You need to tell jQuery that you want a function executes after animation ends. Pass this function as third parameter to the `.animate()` method:

```
$(".small-header").animate({top: "0"}, 500
// now the third parameter:
function () {
    $(".big-header").css("display", "none");
});
```

You need to understand that animations are not built-in in javascript. jQuery just makes it easier to make them, read about what is behind the scenes here - [How do js animations work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6698248/3132718)

Comment: Thanks, but i found other solution - stop() before animate(). And also works :-) I'll check what way is better.