# Javascript move a div smoothly and let another appear

Tags: javascript, animation, html, smoothing

I'm trying to create a site where u can click on the Links in the menu and then the div below the menu moves down **smoothly**, and when it reached the position it should the text appears in the new gap..

I'm currently in the beginning of learning js so dont expect that much..
Somehow the animation does not work and with setInterval i couldnt do it..

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<style>
    /* CSS Document */
    #container{
        border: 1px solid #339999;  
        width: 798px;
    }
    #top{
        background-image:url(images/background1.jpg);
        width: 800xp;
        height: 289px;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
    #bot{
        background-image:url(images/background2.jpg);
        width: 800xp;
        height: 250px;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        margin-top:0px;
    }
    ul.menu{
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 30px;
        font-size:13pt;
        font-family: FrizQuadrata, Calibri;
        color: #339999;
    }
    ul.menu li{
        display:inline;
    }
    #text{
    }
    #footer{
        font-size: 16px;
        color: white;
        font-family: FrizQuadrata, Calibri;
        position: relative;
        top: 150px;
        left: 450px;
    }
    .title{
        font-size:48px;
        color: #339999;
        font-family: FrizQuadrata, Calibri;
    }
    .subtitle{
        font-size:33px;
        color: #339999;
        font-family: FrizQuadrata, Calibri;
    }
    #logo{
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
        left: 500px;
    }
    ul li a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: inherit;
    }
    #d0{
    height:80px;
    }
    #d1{
    height:80px;
    }
    #d2{
    height:80px;
    }
    #d3{
    height:80px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var finished = false;
var timeout = null;
function OpenSite(site, finished){
    menu = document.getElementById(site);
    bot = document.getElementById('bot');
    marg = bot.style.marginTop;
    sheight = menu.offsetHeight;
    marg = marg.slice(0,-2);
    intmarg = parseInt(marg, 10);
    intheight = parseInt(sheight, 10);
    bot.style.marginTop = intmarg + 2 + 'px';
    if (intmarg > intheight) {
        finished = true;
    }
    if(finished == false){
        timeout = setTimeout('OpenSite(site, finished)', 500);
        clearTimeOut(timeout)
    }
}
</script> 

</head>

<div id="container">
    <div id="top">
        <div id="logo">
            <span class="title">INTERPRESA</span><br />
            <span class="subtitle">Consulting GmbH</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="text">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="javascript:OpenSite('d0', false)">Projektmanagement</a>&nbsp; &nbsp; </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:OpenSite('d1', false)">Unternehmensberatung</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:OpenSite('d2', false)">Interimsmanagement</a>  &nbsp; &nbsp; </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:OpenSite('d3', false)">Finanzwesen</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="d0">
        d0<br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>
        <div id="d1">
        d1<br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>
        <div id="d2">
        d2<br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>
        <div id="d3">
        d3<br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bot" style="margin-top:0px;">
        <div id="footer">
            <table cellpadding="3">
                <tr>
                    <td>Schützenegg 956&nbsp;&nbsp;·</td>
                    <td>5728 Hontenschwil</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Tel. 062 773 80 00 ·</td>
                    <td> Fax 062 773 80 05</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">info@interpresa.ch</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to change `'OpenSite(site, finished)'` by `'OpenSite('+site+','+ finished+')'` and removing `clearTimeOut(timeout)`. But keep in mind https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21

Answer (score 1):

I opened the page in Firefox with Firebug running to see what I could see.

### Error

Clicked on Projektmanagement

clearTimeOut is not defined

I don't know what the clearTimeOut function is and I don't know what you're trying to do with it, but 
Firefox doesn't recognise it, so let's start again.

### Stage 1

Check for basic errors and problems:

Notice at the bottom of your file you have put an empty body element and you've put all your div elements outside the body element.
I don't know if that's causing the problem, but it is very odd.

Strange global variables and how to declare variables:

I don't know why you declared `finished` as a global variable.  You use it as a parameter in the `OpenSite` function and so it is locally scoped so this global variable is superfluous. Likewise `timeout`. You don't actually need it at all, but if you did, a locally scoped variable would be fine.

When declaring variables within the scope of function, be sure to use the word `var`, otherwise they become global variables. Declare them all in one comma-delimited statement at the top of the function.  If you don't, the declarations are hoisted to the top of the function anyway so you might as well make the code as readable as possible by putting them there in the first place.

Naming conventions:

`OpenSite` is a function not a constructor so should be in camel case:
`openSite`

I also changed variables like `intmarg` to `intMarg`.  They're just so much more readable.

### Stage 2

Separate markup from script

I know you are just starting with javascript, but it's better to start with the Good Parts (see Doug Crockford's book) and best
practices.  Put your javascript code into a separate file.

I've separated your original page into 2 files:
animation.html
animation.js

It is not good practice to embed javascript in html elements.  We normally add event listeners to elements programatically.
However, you're not using one of the well-known libraries like YAHOO's YUI, or jQuery so I don't want to get too complicated with adding event handlers programmatically.

I think it would be much clearer if you added an event handler to the onclick event of each menu item instead of using the href attribute. It's not good practice to use the javascript protocol. Can't remember the details but I think it's a security risk.

So, change the menu items by adding a handler to the onclick event. Change the css so that
you get a pointer cursor when you hover over the menu items:
    ul li a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: inherit;
        cursor:pointer;
    }

I changed a few other css details just to make it easier to see what was going on.

### Stage 3

Take baby steps.  Comment out everything in the OpenSite function and add one line at a time.  Use alert
to check each line is doing what you expect.

```
alert(site);
```

then:

```
menu = document.getElementById(site);
alert(menu.offsetHeight);
```

then:

```
menu = document.getElementById(site);
bot = document.getElementById('bot');
marg = bot.style.marginTop;
alert(marg);
```

etc.

Note here that marg has the value "0px". You obviously realised it's not a number because you call parseInt later. But then:

```
menu = document.getElementById(site);
bot = document.getElementById('bot');
marg = bot.style.marginTop;
//marg.slice(0,-2);
marg = parseInt(marg);
alert(marg);
```

I presume you're trying to remove "px" from marg with that odd `slice` call. I'm sure you've got mixed up with the parameters there somewhere.  Why not call parseInt right away?

### Stage 4

After reading [Smooth javascript animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322228/smooth-javascript-animation) I separated out the `openSite` function from a `move` function to avoid the repeated calls to `getElementById` etc.

### Stage 5

I reduced the interval on your setTimeout and played around with values. Calling `move` every millisecond seemed more jerky to me and every 24 milliseconds was about the smoothest, but you can experiment with that yourself.

### Stage 6

Consider very seriously using a modern framework like jQuery or YUI because animation is, frankly, not for novice programmers and the endless cross-browser quirks are best left to experienced teams of programmers.

### Final points

I have uploaded a version of this to http://selfstudy-online.co.uk/js/animation.html.  Let me know if it answers some of your questions or at least gets you on the right track.  I am not satisfied with the smoothness of my version and that seems to be a key element of your question.  It isn't completely clear how the final look and feel would work because I don't have a copy of your background images.  Do you have a version uploaded somewhere of your first attempt?